# Why does the timestamp on an item created in the past have a greater value then the current time

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to set an expiry on a password reset token. To do this, my token is inserted into my database with ON_UPDATE_CURRENT_TIMESTAMP before it is sent to the user via email. When the user clicks on the link in the email to reset his password, i will verify his token, and check if it has already expired.

To do this, i pull the timestamp of the token out, convert it to a UNIX timestamp via strtotime() and then compare it with the value from time().If the difference between the timestamps are greater than a set value, it is deemed to have expired.

However, when i echo out the timestamps, i notice that the timestamp for the token is of a higher value then the timestamp generated by time(). If UNIX timestamps represent the number of seconds after jan 1 1970, why does a timestamp generated in the past have a value that is greater than the value of a timestamp generated now?

My code(extract):

```
while($checktoken=$verifyuser->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {
            $userid=$checktoken["UserID"];
            $creationdate=$checktoken["CreationDate"];
        }
        $time=time();
        $creationdate=strtotime($creationdate);
        $diff=$creationdate - $time ;
        $limit=60*60*24;//60 sec*60min*24 hrs -> 1 day
        //token has expired
        if($diff > $limit)
        {
            echo"Your token has expired, please get a new one <a href='#'>here</a>";
        }
        else
        {
            $valid="true";
        }
```

When echoed, i get the values

```
Creationdate:1388626104,time:1388600526, Diff:25578, limit:86400(24 hours)
```

Why is the creationdate timestamp greater then the "time" timestamp?

Comment: Obvious question first, have you verified that the time and timezone settings are the same between the database server and the webserver?

Comment: Timezone difference between PHP and MySQL server?

Comment: Im currently on localhost, how would i check and set the timezone setting?

Comment: If you run this query, you can see what timezone your mysql server is using `SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone`

Comment: @adear11 the results of the query are SYSTEM, which i assume is my current computer time. I done a little googling and managed to change the default timezone in the php.ini file to my local timezone now. Thanks!

Comment: Also is that compare is correct ? 
$diff= $creationdate - $time ;
Is't it $diff=$time- $creationdate  ;
With the first line the difference will be always -ve and the function will always return true.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty Yep, i realise my mistake, the comparison should be done with $diff=$time-$creationdate as the $time value will always be greater than $creationdate since it is generated later. ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm just putting this here in case any readers in the future come across the same problem as me.

You can run the following code to see the timezone used by your server(apache in my case)

```
if (date_default_timezone_get()) {
    echo 'date_default_timezone_set: ' . date_default_timezone_get() . '<br />';
}

if (ini_get('date.timezone')) {
    echo 'date.timezone: ' . ini_get('date.timezone');
}
```

You then check your mysql server timezone by running the following code in your SQL server(I used PHPMYADMIN)

```
SELECT @@global.time_zone, @@session.time_zone
```

. In my case my SQL server's timezone was my computer's timezone but my apache's timezone was Europe/London, which caused the discrepancy.

I solved it by changing the default timezone for my apache server by going to the php.ini file and changing the default values to my local timezone.( you can look for the full list of php timezones on google, and then edit your php.ini file accordingly.)